Fresh Debian 12 (Bookworm) netinstall, no (more) internet
Installed the Debian OS ok, then manually installed some 3-4 GB of kde-standard over the ethernet just fine; booted into it and, surprise! internet not working
root@kellian:/home/kellogs# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:8c:60:58:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.103/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp2s0
       valid_lft 7065sec preferred_lft 7065sec
    inet6 fe80::224:8cff:fe60:5843/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I can see it under DHCP client list too on the router web GUI, but KDE's "Connections - System Settings" says "never used", and the internet is not accessible.
root@kellian:/home/kellogs# sudo service networking restart && sudo service NetworkManager restart - it does renew the DHCP lease.
root@kellian:/home/kellogs# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.481 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.343 ms

root@kellian:/home/kellogs# traceroute serverfault.com
serverfault.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `serverfault.com' on position 1 (argc 1)

enp2s0's connection name also not present in KDE systray list of connections. A tethered phone is present there though.
root@kellian:/home/kellogs# telnet 192.168.1.1 80
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> q

Can't find anything telling related to network/ethernet in logs.
Thank you
